# Generic Method That GetTheData of any object and return it to list

Tags: c#, generics, datatable

**I have created a generic method that get All data from a table and Give me A list of T that is compiled to a specified object on run time.** 

My connection,commands,procedure are working perfectly , but when filling The DataTable with my objects by row looping it prompts me an error : 
 Column 'ApplicationName' does not belong to table .
I have tried to look for solution from the past answers but it did not helps me.

Any Help would be thankfull!
Here is my code below :::

```
public List<T> GetElement<T>( string procedureName) where T : new()
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
            List<T> ThisList = new List<T>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                T tObject = new T();
                PropertyInfo[] properties = tObject.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (var prop in properties)
                {
                    if (tObject.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(tObject, row[prop.Name], null);
                    }
                }
                ThisList.Add(tObject);
            }
            return ThisList;
        }
```

Call That Method from an other class:

```
 public List<Application> GEtAllElements()
           {
          return TestMyCodeDAO.GetElement<Application>( "GetAllApplications");
           }
```

And In The program.cs (RunTime):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationBO.GEtAllElements();
        }
```

Base on developpers request : Here are the Class Application .

```
public class Application 
{
#region private 
private int _ApplicationID;
private string _ApplicationName;
private string _ApplicationUrl;
private Byte[] _ApplicationImage
private string _ImageName;
#endregion
#region public 
public ApplicationID{get{return _ApplicationID;} 
set{_ApplicationID=value;}}
public string ApplicationName{get{return _ApplicationName;} set{_ApplicationName=value;}}
public string ApplicationUrl{get{return _ApplicationUrl;}
set{_ApplicationUrl=value;}}
public Byte[] ApplicationImage{get{return _ApplicationImage;} set{_ApplicationImage=value;}}
public string ImageName{get{return _ImageName;} 
set{_ImageName=value;}}
#endregion 

}
```

Comment: "My connection,commands,procedure are working perfectly" No, they are not. You should be disposing your connection, commands and data adapters.

Comment: Have you got a class called Application then? And can you confirm if there's a field in the dataset you are returning from GetAllApplications called ApplicationName?

Comment: Particulary disposing of the Connection is mandatory. You should be using a using block, to make certain that is taken care off. This is just general rules, it should ahve nothing to do with your current problem. But in order to help you with that one we would need the Full Exception Information (Class Thrown, Stacktrace) as well as the line it is thrown from.

Comment: If you have multiple classes that inherit from a base class that has an `ApplicationName` property, then you would want to constrain your generic type to that base type, like `where T: YourBaseType`.

Comment: @Christopher  The Connection and sqlDataAdapter filled succesfully my DataTable (using the command for sure )

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes ! I should dispose my conncetion and SqlDataAdapter in {finally} .... But This is not the reason for such error , since the Exception is prompted after the DataTable is succesfully filled with data

Comment: I will Edit the Class Application and Add the SqlCommand (even it is not necessary)

Comment: @markdibe: As I wrote above, we need proper Exception details: Type of Exception, Stacktrace, line it is thrown from. With anything less we can not help you to debug this.

Comment: @Christopher I truly want to show you the exception , but i am not in the company (work place), if i share the Exception tomorrow , would you reply me ?

Comment: On the face of it there's a mismatch between the field names in 'row' and the property names in properties, put breakpoints there and check on that.